# Creating Window Class Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create couple of windows classed using Tkinter. I get no error when I run the code but it doesn't display anything. Am I missing anything?

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = startpage(root)  

class startpage:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Main Page")
        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg = "blue")
        self.frame  = Frame(self.master, bg = 'blue')
        self.frame.pack()


    def EntryWin(self):
        self.Entry_win = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Entrypage(self.Entry_win)

class Entrypage:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Entry Page")
        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg = "green")
        self.frame  = Frame(self.master, bg = 'blue')
        self.frame.pack() 



if __name__ == 'main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have misspelt `__main__` and also need to import tkinter library. See my answer i have made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelt `__main__` as `main__` when you call the `main` function.

Also import tkinter at the beginning of the code, and add `root.mainloop()` in the `main()`.

`from tkinter import *`

**Here is the corrected code:**

```py
from tkinter import *

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = startpage(root)
    root.mainloop()

class startpage:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Main Page")
        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg = "blue")
        self.frame = Frame(self.master, bg = 'blue')
        self.frame.pack()

    def EntryWin(self):
        self.Entry_win = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Entrypage(self.Entry_win)

        self.master.mainloop()

class Entrypage:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Entry Page")
        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg = "green")
        self.frame = Frame(self.master, bg = 'blue')
        self.frame.pack()

        self.master.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks Somraj, It seems I get a strange problem. The code run but it outputs the frame somewhere in my laptop not in the main screen. I only have single screen laptop. The reason I noticed it was, when I run another project, and the window from other program is generated, I see several windows including from this program but I run this program on its own, I can see the windows. I am not sure if I make sense.

Comment: Could it be because of this?runfile('C:/Users/khisr/OneDrive/Documents/PythonProjects/Dubai_Project/Tutoring.py', wdir='C:/Users/khisr/OneDrive/Documents/PythonProjects/Dubai_Project')

Comment: **The code run but it outputs the frame somewhere in my laptop not in the main screen.** - What do you see when you run the program? Your code generates a GUI with a `blue` background.

Comment: I see nothing, no blue screen background but I when I run other programs I find the blue screen minimised on the bottom of my screen

Comment: ***but when I run other programs I find the blue screen minimised...*** - It's a strange problem. I'll try to find a solution to this issue in the meantime you try out by closing all the python files and then run this file alone.

Comment: Thanks, I did but didint help. FYI I run the code on Anaconda> Spyder>Python 3.7 .

Comment: Hey @user3064089, if you still having this issue, then try calling `mainloop()` in your GUI. See the answer, I updated it. Cheers!